# Mapping any OS's global input events to another input events with Java

Tags: java, input, operating-system, mapping, hardware

I couldn't come up with a better title, so allow me to elaborate:

There are programs such as [JoyToKey](http://www-en.jtksoft.net/overview), that allowed the user to map button inputs on any joystick to any key event and mouse event. To be frank, I do not know the real underlying implementation here, but it is like either JoyToKey "ubiquitously" sends these mapped inputs to whatever application the user is focusing, or it simply invokes global input events.

So the thing is this, in Java application, if we want to listen to any keyboard or mouse input, we can easily to do that with the `KeyListener` and `MouseListener` classes, but what I am talking here is if I want to create a Java application that listens to all of the user's specified inputs, (be it from joystick, touch screen, or whatever) regardless of which application has focus at the time and map these inputs to other inputs and macro. For instance, if I want to perform Hadoken in Street Fighter, I tell the program "hey, if I press 'P' or 'Joystick 1 Button 10', invoke the following keyboard events respectively 'down arrow' in the first (1/60) millisecond, 'down+right arrow' in the next (1/60) millisecond, 'right arrow' in the next (1/60) millisecond and finally 'Z' in the next (1/60) millisecond".

So what I am looking for here is different from JoyToKey in the following aspect:

1. I am looking for how to write a JoyToKey-like program in **Java**.
2. not limited to Joystick only. Allows user to map all sort of hardware inputs to any other hardware input as well.

Due to the nature of Java and we are invoking the OS directly, I am concern about the cross-platform capability. The underlying mechanism of each OS might be a little different, but anyway, is this possible in Java? If so, which Java's API should I be looking for? Are there some hardware-specific problems to be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux, check out the [java-gnome](http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/doc/api/4.1/org/gnome/gdk/package-summary.html) bindings. The `org.gnome.gdk` package provides access to system-wide device events.